# How To: moving the touchpad cursor WHILE typing?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, synaptics

I was wondering if anyone knows how to disable the mandate that Ubuntu sets by default that if you are typing, you can not move the touchpad.  I would like to type AND move the touchpad at the same time, and I have not found anything in accessibility, keyboard, or mouse and touchpad settings.  This issue is driving me nuts.  I believe Windows calls this settings "palm detection" if that helps.  Thanks to anyone kind enough to provide some support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a simple terminal command. Open a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad disable-while-typing false
```

---

Note: this command was sourced from [jasomux's post from Ubuntu Forums.](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2379851)

Comment: Ahhhhhh.... so much better :)  Thanks so much stranger!

Comment: Does it require a restart? It hasn't fixed on mine.